# How to find if an event has been fired in workflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow

We are using [Geekq/workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) in Rails app. Here is an example:

```
class Article
  include Workflow
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end
end
```

It is easy to find if a state, for example, `:awaiting_review` has been gone through by:

```
article.current_state < :awaiting_review
```

However, we did not find a method to check if an event has been fired. Is checking if an event has been fired something possible with the workflow's built-in method? Or if not with this workflow, any other can?

Comment: What operation you want to perform on event fired? You can use `before_transition` for performing operation before transition to another state. Hope this will help.

Comment: Just check if an event has been fired for an instance. No operation on the event.

Comment: Then you can use before_transition. Whenever any event will occur it will call transition and before transition you can log it.

Comment: Yes, we can use log. I am looking to see if there is built-in method for this.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can catch event of on_create and on_update as there are callbacks present for it in ActiveRecord, but for change_state in workflow, you need to override the transition of workflow, by:

```
class Article < BaseModel

include Workflow
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected

    on_transition do |from, to, event, *event_args|
       self.update_attribute(:status, to)
       # this triggers on_update callback on workflow transition
       # which you can use to log the event now
    end
  end
end

class BaseModel < ActiveRecord
  after_commit :log_create_event, on: [:create]
  after_commit :log_update_event, on: [:update]
  after_commit :log_destroy_event, on: [:destroy]

  def log_create_event
    #log_event('Create')
  end

  def log_update_event
    #log_event('Update')
  end

  def log_destroy_event
    #log_event('Destroy')
  end
end
```